# SQL - Multiple many-to-many relations filtering SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, inner-join

These are my tables:

```
Cadastros (id, nome)
Convenios (id, nome)
Especialidades (id, nome)
Facilidades (id, nome)
```

And the join tables:

```
cadastros_convenios
cadastros_especialidades
cadastros_facilidades
```

The table I'm querying for: Cadastros

I'm using MySQL.

The system will allow the user to select multiple "Convenios", "Especialidades" and "Facilidades". Think of each of these tables as a different type of "tag". The user will be able to select multiple "tags" of each type.

What I want is to select only the results in Cadastros table that are related with ALL the "tags" from the 3 different tables provided. Please note it's not an "OR" relation. It should only return the row from Cadastros if it has a matching link table row for EVERY "tag" provided.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Cadastro.*, Convenio.* FROM Cadastros AS Cadastro
    INNER JOIN cadastros_convenios AS CadastrosConvenio ON(Cadastro.id = CadastrosConvenio.cadastro_id)
INNER JOIN Convenios AS Convenio ON (CadastrosConvenio.convenio_id = Convenio.id AND Convenio.id IN(2,3))
    INNER JOIN cadastros_especialidades AS CadastrosEspecialidade ON (Cadastro.id = CadastrosEspecialidade.cadastro_id)
INNER JOIN Especialidades AS Especialidade ON(CadastrosEspecialidade.especialidade_id = Especialidade.id AND Especialidade.id IN(1))
    INNER JOIN cadastros_facilidades AS CadastrosFacilidade ON (Cadastro.id = CadastrosFacilidade.cadastro_id)
INNER JOIN Facilidades AS Facilidade ON(CadastrosFacilidade.facilidade_id = Facilidade.id AND Facilidade.id IN(1,2))
GROUP BY Cadastro.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 5;
```

I'm using the HAVING clause to try to filter the results based on the number of times it shows (meaning the number of times it has been successfully "INNER JOINED"). So in every case, the count should be equal to the number of different filters I added. So if I add 3 different "tags", the count should be 3. If I add 5 different tags, the count should be 5 and so on. It works fine for a single relation (a single pair of inner joins). When I add the other 2 relations it starts to lose control.

**EDIT**

Here is something that I believe is working (thanks **@Tomalak** for pointing out the solution with sub-queries):

```
    SELECT Cadastro.*, Convenio.*, Especialidade.*, Facilidade.* FROM Cadastros AS Cadastro

    INNER JOIN cadastros_convenios AS CadastrosConvenio ON(Cadastro.id = CadastrosConvenio.cadastro_id)
INNER JOIN Convenios AS Convenio ON (CadastrosConvenio.convenio_id = Convenio.id)

    INNER JOIN cadastros_especialidades AS CadastrosEspecialidade ON (Cadastro.id = CadastrosEspecialidade.cadastro_id)
INNER JOIN Especialidades AS Especialidade ON(CadastrosEspecialidade.especialidade_id = Especialidade.id)

    INNER JOIN cadastros_facilidades AS CadastrosFacilidade ON (Cadastro.id = CadastrosFacilidade.cadastro_id)
INNER JOIN Facilidades AS Facilidade ON(CadastrosFacilidade.facilidade_id = Facilidade.id)

WHERE
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cadastros_convenios WHERE cadastro_id = Cadastro.id AND convenio_id IN(1, 2, 3)) = 3
AND
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cadastros_especialidades WHERE cadastro_id = Cadastro.id AND especialidade_id IN(3)) = 1
AND
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cadastros_facilidades WHERE cadastro_id = Cadastro.id AND facilidade_id IN(2, 3)) = 2

GROUP BY Cadastro.id
```

But I'm concerned about performance. It looks like these 3 sub-queries in the WHERE clause are gonna be over-executed...

**Another solution**

It joins subsequent tables only if the previous joins were a success (if no rows match one of the joins, the next joins are gonna be joining an empty result-set) (thanks **@DRapp** for this one)

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
  Cadastro.*
   FROM 
  ( SELECT Qualify1.cadastro_id
       from 
             ( SELECT cc1.cadastro_id
                  FROM cadastros_convenios cc1
                  WHERE cc1.convenio_id IN (1, 2, 3)
                  GROUP by cc1.cadastro_id 
                  having COUNT(*) = 3 ) Qualify1

             JOIN
             ( SELECT ce1.cadastro_id
                  FROM cadastros_especialidades ce1
                  WHERE ce1.especialidade_id IN( 3 )
                  GROUP by ce1.cadastro_id
                  having COUNT(*) = 1 ) Qualify2
                ON (Qualify1.cadastro_id = Qualify2.cadastro_id)

                  JOIN 
                  ( SELECT cf1.cadastro_id
                       FROM cadastros_facilidades cf1
                       WHERE cf1.facilidade_id IN (2, 3)
                       GROUP BY cf1.cadastro_id 
                       having COUNT(*) = 2 ) Qualify3
                  ON (Qualify2.cadastro_id = Qualify3.cadastro_id) ) FullSet
  JOIN Cadastros AS Cadastro
     ON FullSet.cadastro_id = Cadastro.id

     INNER JOIN cadastros_convenios AS CC 
        ON (Cadastro.id = CC.cadastro_id)
        INNER JOIN Convenios AS Convenio
           ON (CC.convenio_id = Convenio.id)

     INNER JOIN cadastros_especialidades AS CE 
        ON (Cadastro.id = CE.cadastro_id)
        INNER JOIN Especialidades AS Especialidade
           ON (CE.especialidade_id = Especialidade.id)

     INNER JOIN cadastros_facilidades AS CF
        ON (Cadastro.id = CF.cadastro_id)
        INNER JOIN Facilidades AS Facilidade
           ON (CF.facilidade_id = Facilidade.id)
GROUP BY Cadastro.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Emphasis mine

> "It should only return the row from Cadastros **if it has a matching row** for EVERY "tag" provided."

"where there is a matching row"-problems are easily solved with `EXISTS`.

**EDIT** After some clarification, I see that using `EXISTS` is not enough. Comparing the actual row counts is necessary:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  Cadastros c
WHERE
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cadastros_facilidades WHERE cadastro_id = c.id AND id IN (2,3)) = 2 
  AND
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cadastros_especialidades WHERE cadastro_id = c.id AND id IN (1)) = 1
  AND
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cadastros_facilidades WHERE cadastro_id = c.id AND id IN (1,2)) = 2
```

The indexes on the link tables should be `(cadastro_id, id)` for this query.

Comment: This does not work because it makes an OR relation on each link table -> WHERE cadastro_id = c.id AND **id IN (2,3)**. That means it could return, for example, a row from Cadastro that is associated with Facilidade 2 but not 3.

    "It should only return the row from Cadastros if it has **a matching row for EVERY "tag"** provided."

Comment: @CaioLandau Ah!. Use subqueries like `WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cadastros_facilidades WHERE cadastro_id = c.id AND id IN (2,3)) = 2`, then

Comment: I see how this can solve the issue. It's a solution I haven't thought before, but I have one concern. I will be working with large amounts of data. Specially in the Especialidades, Convenios and Facilidades tables. There won't really be a lot of rows in these tables, but they generate larger link tables of course. Wouldn't making 3 separated sub-queries highly impact on performance?

Comment: Just edited the question with the query I've built to solve the issue. I've made some small tests and it seems like everything is being returned as expected. Maybe now I should fill a really big database with dummy data and make some tests to see how well it goes.


Looks like I can't +1 (or something like that, this is my first post here). Well, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Caio Right, you cannot up-vote unless you have 15 rep. I would dis-recommend doing a `SELECT *` for every table you have unless you really, *really* need every field. Also joining every table you have into that query just for the sake of it might not be the best idea.

Comment: About not doing `SELECT *` for every table, just taking it out would make my query any faster, like this: `SELECT Cadastro.* FROM Cadastros AS Cadastro)` instead of `SELECT Cadastro.*, Convenio.*, Especialidade.*, Facilidade.* FROM Cadastros AS Cadastro`?

Comment: And about not doing all the joins, those joins are going to be dynamically generated, so they will only be there if there was a filter using the table. If no filters are selected on that table, it's not gonna be joined. For Example, if I only want to filter using Convenios, I won't join Facilidades and Especialidades (and won't include the matching WHERE, of course)

Comment: @CaioLandau Yes, not selecting fields you do not need makes the query faster. On the other hand, you can optimize the query when you have a few hundred thousand rows and it turns slow. I just wanted to caution you about letting the server do unnecessary work.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the tables (records), WHERE-based subqueries, running a test on every row CAN SIGNIFICANTLY hit performance.  I have restructured it which MIGHT better help, but only you would be able to confirm.  The premise here is to have the first table based on getting distinct IDs that meet the criteria, join THAT set to the next qualifier criteria... joined to the FINAL set.  Once that has been determined, use THAT to join to your main table and its subsequent links to get the details you are expecting.  You also had an overall group by by the ID which will eliminate all other nested entries as found in the support details table.

All that said, lets take a look at this scenario.  Start with the table that would be EXPECTED TO HAVE THE LOWEST RESULT SET to join to the next and next.  if cadastros_convenios has IDs that match all the criteria include IDs 1-100, great, we know at MOST, we'll have 100 ids.

Now, these 100 entries are immediately JOINED to the 2nd qualifying criteria... of which, say it only matches ever other... for simplicity, we are now matched on 50 of the 100.

Finally, JOIN to the 3rd qualifier based on the 50 that qualified and you get 30 entries.  So, within these 3 queries you are now filtered down to 30 entries with all the qualifying criteria handled up front.   NOW, join to the Cadastros and then subsequent tables for the details based ONLY on the 30 that qualified.

Since your original query would eventually TRY EVERY "ID" for the criteria, why not pre-qualify it up front with ONE query and get just those that hit, then move on.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      Cadastro.*, 
      Convenio.*, 
      Especialidade.*, 
      Facilidade.* 
   FROM 
      ( SELECT Qualify1.cadastro_id
           from 
                 ( SELECT cc1.cadastro_id
                      FROM cadastros_convenios cc1
                      WHERE cc1.convenio_id IN (1, 2, 3)
                      GROUP by cc1.cadastro_id 
                      having COUNT(*) = 3 ) Qualify1

                 JOIN
                 ( SELECT ce1.cadastro_id
                      FROM cadastros_especialidades ce1
                      WHERE ce1.especialidade_id IN( 3 )
                      GROUP by ce1.cadastro_id
                      having COUNT(*) = 1 ) Qualify2
                    ON Qualify1.cadastro_id = Qualify2.cadastro_id

                      JOIN 
                      ( SELECT cf1.cadastro_id
                           FROM cadastros_facilidades cf1
                           WHERE cf1.facilidade_id IN (2, 3)
                           GROUP BY cf1.cadastro_id 
                           having COUNT(*) = 2 ) Qualify3
                      ON Qualify2.cadastro_id = Qualify3.cadastro_id ) FullSet
      JOIN Cadastros AS Cadastro
         ON FullSet.Cadastro_id = Cadastro.Cadastro_id

         INNER JOIN cadastros_convenios AS CC 
            ON Cadastro.id = CC.cadastro_id
            INNER JOIN Convenios AS C
               ON CC.convenio_id = C.id

         INNER JOIN cadastros_especialidades AS CE 
            ON Cadastro.id = CE.cadastro_id
            INNER JOIN Especialidades AS E
               ON CE.especialidade_id = E.id

         INNER JOIN cadastros_facilidades AS CF
            ON Cadastro.id = CF.cadastro_id
            INNER JOIN Facilidades AS F 
               ON CF.facilidade_id = F.id
```